# Sqlite error 14 with .NET Core 2.2 API and EF Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I started a new project with code first and migrations to a Sqlite database. The `update` command created the file at the root of the project and using SQLite Studio I can open the file as expected and see the created table structure.

I've created a DbContext file with the following code representing the one table/class and the associated connection string:

```
    public DbSet<PropertyTax> PropertyTaxes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = "InstallmentCalculator.db" };
        var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
        options.UseSqlite(connection);
    }
```

In my Startup.cs file, the ConfigureServices section contains the following:

`services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<InstallmentCalculatorContext>();`

and in the Configure section I've put this code to verify that the database has been created:

```
        using (var db = new InstallmentCalculatorContext())
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
```

and...that's where everything goes *boom*.

SqliteException: SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

I've seen some discussion on this issue, but nothing terribly recent, and nothing that resolved the problem.

Comment: Do you have a password set?

Comment: No, no password set at this point. Just trying to get .NET to recognize that the database is there and accessible.